# Align elements in navbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a little navigation bar with a search-bar and a login.
My problem is that normally I would use `display:flex` but this time I want to try something else.
So I decided to give my `<li>`-Elements the property `display:inline`, which, of course, doesn't work out for me.

**CSS**:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
html {
    display:block;
}
body {

  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.42857143;

}

a {
  color: #00B7FF;
}
.navbar-default {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.container-fluid {
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-left:30px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.navbar-default ul {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline;
}

.navbar-default li {
    display:inline;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<nav class="navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-default nav">
            <li>
                <div id="search" class="search-navbar">
                    <input type="search"> 
                    <input type="button" value="Search">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div id="login" class="login-navbar">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="password">
                    <input type="button" value="Sign in">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is a working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rvfd5h5e/

What I want is to place the search-bar on the left (but not at the edge) and the login on the right.

I hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out using `display:inline-block` and `float:right`

**CSS**

```
.navbar-default ul {
    list-style: none;
    display:block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 3em;
}
.navbar-default li, .navbar-default li div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.navbar-default li:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/rvfd5h5e/2/)**

Comment: works good, but why do i need line-height:3em for positioning in the center?

Comment: You can center with a lot of techniques...line-height is one of them - http://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: thank you for the link, will mark your answer as soon as i can

Answer (score 1):

You can make your display inline-block so it does not add a break.

```
.navbar-default li {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santon/rvfd5h5e/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline` to both the `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

you can this css:

```
width: 50%;
float: left;
display: inline;
```

for div inside first li
and

```
display: inline;
float: right;
```

above css for div in second li